# quantization vector with numpy/pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, quantization

I have created quantized values as: `{0.0, 0.5, 1.0}` and would like to do quantization for a vector based on the set. For instance, given vector `[0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.6, 0.6]` would be transferred into `[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5]`.

Please guide me fastest way using python/numpy/pytorch. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=lambda#lambda-expressions) and [`lambda()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=lambda#lambda-expressions)

you can get the round off nearest to 0.5 with `round(x * 2) / 2`

```
a = [0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.6, 0.6]

list(map(lambda x: round(x * 2) / 2, a))
```

output :

```
[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for my case.
In fact, I would like to do for a dynamic range of the base, I mean not only for step of 0.5. For example, with step is 0.1, we have a base as {0.0, 0.1, 0.2,..., 0.9, 1.0} (even higher density with smaller step). I believe I can solve the question based on your answer.

Comment: in that case just use [round()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round)  `round(n, 1)` where n is the float you want to pass.

Comment: oh, that's right! Many thanks again for your help.